# Check if user already viewed specific page

Tags: javascript, php, html, menu

I'm coding an e-learning with html and javascript , but lately I faced an issue that i can't resolve so I migrated to php but unfortunately with no result ,
When the users opens the first page the menu appears but not clickable , each item must appear once he watched the video , means visited a page .

The menu contains links to different html pages , for example when I visit page1.html the menu opens the next page so i can click and go ...this has been solved by the code attached , but the issue is that i need to store the changes I made for example when i arrive to page 5 and want to see again page 1  i will only see page 2 even if i already visited 2 and 3 that must be active from previous pages once visited

please check my code and advise me :

I have created a java script code that works only item by item next naVIGATION , but not saving values

```
function session() {

    if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {
      // alert("Your n visit");

  document.getElementById("itemId").style.pointerEvents = "";





    } 


    else {
        document.cookie = "visited";

// alert("Your firsttttt visit");

  document.getElementById('myvid').addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  //alert("Well done , you can go to the next chapter now!");
  document.getElementById("itemId").style.pointerEvents = "";
```

Html code

```
<li><a href="../2/2.php"style="pointer-events: none;" id="itemId" >INIT Page</a></li>
```

Comment: you can store a new session value for each page visit

Comment: do you have an example please